# How to create content provider for sharing PDF file through implicit intent to another app?

Tags: java, android, pdf, fileprovider

I am making project for my school. In this app, I am downloading pdf files from Firebase and storing it on app's external dir. After downloading, I want to through implicit intent to other pdf reader app to display downloaded pdf. I searched web for 2 days straight for how to create content provider but all tutorial are old and used android.support.v4 content provider and I don't know how to create custom content provider. I tried using androidx.core.content.fileprovider and it also created content uri but when launched, pdf reader screen pops but nothing is displayed, just title of file is displayed.

output of fileUri.toString- content://com.syrous.studentlibraryjava.fileprovider/document/mse1_dagaeg.pdf

```
    Uri fileUri = getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName()+".fileprovider", localFile); //This is the in build function, just accepted import. 
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/pdf");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
```

Here is the declaration of provider in manifest---->

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.syrous.yccestudentlibraryjava.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Here is the file_paths ----->

```
  <paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="document"
        path="mse1/"/>
  </paths>
```

I'm not sure, if i declared file_path correct. I have my pdf file inside external_folder/files/mse1/file_to_open. If there is any correction in file_path, Please suggest me.

I have permission to read and write external storage declared in manifest and also asked for it

Help me guys!!
[Emulator Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxLI5.png)

Comment: You start with unknown variable `localFile'. Should we know what that is? Start better please.

Comment: And `getUriForFile()` is your own function. We dont know what it does.

Comment: Further you should tell us the value of fileUri.toString().

Comment: `not sure, if i declared file_path correct. ` ? You did not declare a file path in your code. As said before: start with it.

Comment: No getUriForFile() is not my own function. I accepted import From FileProvider.getUriForFIle() @blackapps

Comment: @blackapps output of fileUri.toString() - content://com.syrous.studentlibraryjava.fileprovider/document/mse1_xfaefga.pdf

Answer (score 0):

`android:authorities="com.syrous.yccestudentlibraryjava.fileprovider` does not mach `content://com.syrous.studentlibraryjava.fileprovider/document/mse1_xfaefga.pdf`.